# Are finalizers called in the reverse order of making?

Tags: lua

Consider the following code:

```
function fun()
   local o1 = foo:new() -- object with __gc metamethod
   local o2 = bar:new() -- object with __gc metamethod
end
```

Will Lua call the `o2` finalizer before `o1`'s because `o2` was created later than `o1` or is the order finalizers are called undefined?

Comment: In your example, both variables are on the stack and thus not "collected", and the strings are constant and thus not collected either. So the answer would be "at the same time". Afaik.

Comment: You don't have to care about GC order for strings; that's not observable (except for counting garbage). The only thing you have to care about are finalizers (`__gc` metamethod), which are guaranteed to run in a particular order (reverse order of "marking"). See the [5.4 reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.5.3).

Comment: @Luatic: Actually, the string was just for illustration purposes. In the real life example the objects to be collected have finalizers attached and I was wondering about the order in which those finalizers get called.

Comment: @Andreas you should rewrite your example to demonstrate that, something like `local o1 = foo:new() -- object with __gc metamethod`

Comment: @Nifim Right, I've done that now and also changed the question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is guaranteed that `o2` will be finalized before `o1`

Objects will be finalized in the reverse order that they were "marked". An object is "marked" for finalization when the metatable is set with a `__gc` metamethod.

Reference: https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#2.5.3

> At the end of each garbage-collection cycle, **the finalizers are called in the reverse order that the objects were marked for finalization**, among those collected in that cycle; that is, the first finalizer to be called is the one associated with the object marked last in the program. The execution of each finalizer may occur at any point during the execution of the regular code.

> For an object (table or userdata) to be finalized when collected, you must mark it for finalization. **You mark an object for finalization when you set its metatable and the metatable has a __gc metamethod.** Note that if you set a metatable without a __gc field and later create that field in the metatable, the object will not be marked for finalization.

---

In this example `o1` will be finalized before `o2`:

```lua
function fun()
   local o1 = foo:new() -- object without __gc metamethod
   local o2 = bar:new() -- object without __gc metamethod

   setmetatable(o2, metaWithGC)
   setmetatable(o1, metaWithGC)

end
```